# Anaconda 5.0.0 Installation on Windows 10 not working properly

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

My old anaconda installation behaved strangely (updating didn't work properly but `conda list` did work fine).

So I decided to reinstall Anaconda, that's where the problems started. After uninstalling the old Anaconda version via the Win10 remove programs tool, I downloaded the installer from the website and installed it.

After Installation, no navigator was available, `conda list`says the command `conda` is misspelled or missing, and when opening the anaconda prompt is just says `anaconda3\scripts\activate.bat` is misspelled or missing.

The installed Python 3.6.2 version works just fine (confirmed via `python --version`).

I tried reinstalling multiple times, with reboots in between each step, and even on different drives. Nothing worked.

If someone has an idea what is causing this strange behavior I'd be very thankful.

Comment: What are the contents of your PATH environment variable?

Comment: I used the installation without adding it to PATH. Whcih according to the continuum website should do just fine if I could start the navigator (if it was installed)
But I also thought of this and added the anaconda folder to path
`C:\Users\MYNAME\Anaconda3`
Alas this did not help much...

Comment: Did your previous Anaconda installation add anything to the PATH?

Comment: Hmm doesnt seem like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after the Windows Fall update a reinstall solved the problem!
Seems something was amiss in the windows installation afterall!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I rolled back to version 4.4.0. Nothing I tried worked for versions 5.0.0 and 5.0.1